# Where is the printer default option configuration file?

Tags: cups

I am using CUPS 1.6.1.

I have a problem with printing the pages with one side only. Default option is "one-sided", as in the CUPS web interface configuration. But when I do the printing, it prints out "two-sided-long-edge" result.

I want to configure it manually. Where is the exact configuration file location? Whenever I make the changes from the CUPS web interface for default options, the /etc/cups/printers.conf time is modified, but content is not changed. But in the web interface, the default option is changed. Which file is the default options configuration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The setting is edited in the PPD file: `/etc/cups/ppd/foo.ppd` where `foo` is the printer name.

The normal way to modify these settings from the command line is the `lpoptions` command. It changes the system settings if executed as root, and the per-user settings (stored in `~/.cups/lpoptions`) otherwise.